# Eclipse Grizzly servlet-deployer

Tags: maven, glassfish, grizzly

Is there a replacement for the package `grizzly-servlet-deployer` for the recent versions of Eclipse Grizzly (2.0 / 3.0)?

This package existed for older versions: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.grizzly/grizzly-servlet-deployer

Answer (score 1):

No.  Keep in mind I haven't worked on Grizzly in years, but if I recall correctly, we removed that module in later releases of Grizzly in favor of programmatic registration of Servlet artifacts using the same API exposed by later servlet specifications.